# reset ng-idle after authorization

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

ng-idle on my application works fine. But after timeout , I have a pop up that asks for user credentials again. So what is the way to reset ng-idle and start watching again after popup authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Idle.watch(); to your app

Answer (score 0):

Once user types his credentials and clicks on submit 
for example code

```
<button (click)="submit()" label="submit"></button>
```

Inside submit() method, You can write idle.watch();

```
submit() {
    idle.watch();
  }
```